# In py.test, what's the point of marking fixture as fixture?

Tags: python, pytest

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def my_fixture():
    data = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
    return data

def test_my_fixture(my_fixture):
    assert my_fixture['x'] == 1
```

**What's the benefit of marking `my_fixture` as a pytest `fixture`? It seems like the fixture's benefit is the same with `my_fixture` just being a normal function, removing the decorator.**

I see the benefit only here where `my_fixture` is run simply by providing it as a parameter to `test_my_fixture`:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def my_fixture():
    print "\nI'm the fixture"

def test_my_fixture(my_fixture):
    print "I'm the test"
```

This should print:

```
I'm the fixture
I'm the test
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do not declare `my_fixture` as a fixture, then the test will not be able to use it as a fixture:

```
import pytest

def my_fixture():
    data = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
    return data

def test_my_fixture(my_fixture):
    assert my_fixture['x'] == 1
```

This script leads to an error:

```
  def test_my_fixture(my_fixture):
E       fixture 'my_fixture' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capsys, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_xml_property, recwarn, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
```

The purpose of the fixtures is to prepare something before the test(s). And to kill it afterward. And NOT to be part of the test (e.g. in logging, reporting, ways of exception handling, etc). It is kind of a pre-condition, created by something else, and just given to the test.

If you just declare it as a function, and use it as a function, it is a function, not a fixture. And its failures become the failures of the test, not the general framework run.

Consider this example:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def my_fixture():
    data = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
    print('prepare')
    yield data
    print('destroy')

def test_my_fixture(my_fixture):
    print('test it')
    assert my_fixture['x'] == 1
```

Also in this example try uncommenting the raising lines, and see the difference. It will be ERROR vs FAILURE. It is critical for how the test results are interpreted and handled later (e.g., by the developers, QA engineers, or whoever analyses the test results).

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def my_fixture():
    print('prepare')
    # raise Exception('Oops')
    yield None
    print('destroy')

def test_my_fixture(my_fixture):
    # raise Exception('Booms!')
    print('test it')
```

In the fixture:

```
======================================= test session starts ========================================
collected 1 item                                                                                    

t.py E

============================================== ERRORS ==============================================
________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_my_fixture _________________________________

    @pytest.fixture()
    def my_fixture():
        data = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
        print('prepare')
>       raise Exception('Oops')
E       Exception: Oops

t.py:7: Exception
===================================== 1 error in 0.03 seconds ======================================
```

In the test or any function called from the test:

```
======================================= test session starts ========================================
collected 1 item                                                                                    

t.py F

============================================= FAILURES =============================================
_________________________________________ test_my_fixture __________________________________________

my_fixture = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}

    def test_my_fixture(my_fixture):
>       raise Exception('Booms!')
E       Exception: Booms!

t.py:12: Exception
===================================== 1 failed in 0.03 seconds =====================================
```

Also note that the fixtures have scopes: session, module, function. It will be difficult to demonstrate in a short example, but in that case, the fixture will be prepared and destroyed only once (usually only once) for multiple tests within that scope. This is important for the heavy-weight fixtures, such as the database pre-population. Such fixtures usually reside in the `conftest.py` pseudo-plugin in the directory structure (NB: this is not a regular module to be imported! by design, at least).